# How can I recreate the lighting and the glass in this?

Tags: materials, lighting, glass

[image]I am new to blender so please bear with me if this is a silly question. I have been trying to recreate this cool image and got stuck at the lighting in those glass boxes and the glass shader.
Can someone help me with this please.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So... How does your attempt look like?
What have you tried and why are you not satisfied with the result?

Comment: This is how it turned out

Comment: Doesn't look too far off, except for the lack of refraction, i guess? Again - please describe a bit more in detail what you have tried so far? What material setup, what render engine, etc.? What exactly are you not content with?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. I want the glass to have not much reflections and kind of a tinted look, the material set up is, I have plugged in a translucent and transparent shader with BSDF. For the lighting I have a 500W point light  inside that glass room. I am using cycles. That soft lighting in that glass room is what I am stuck at. Is there any way I can recreate it the same way it looks in the reference picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what kind of look you are going for (as I said, you are pretty close to the reference already IMO), but I noticed one thing:

You have (physically correctly) used a solidify-modifier to hollow out the glass. The other artist has not, his "windows" are essentially massive blocks of glass.
With the solidify-modifier disabled, it looks like this: [image]

Not quite there, but closer, I'd say

Other advice would be to maybe add a little volume scatter to the material and tweak the outside lighting a bit. That's all I can think of right now, hope it helps!